# Problem with icon arrangement in the laucher

Tags: unity, launcher, icons

I'm having a problem with selecting and arranging the icons in the launcher panel.  I had the same problem in 13.10.  I hoped it would go away in 14.04 but unfortunately it hasn't.

First, when I right click items in the launcher, and select lock or unlock nothing happens.  Icons for closed programs don't disappear, and when I try to lock apps to the launcher they don't stay once they are closed.  Also, when I restart the computer none of the apps I 'unlocked' went away.  They are still there.

Also (and maybe worse...) drag and drop rearrangement of the icons doesn't work.  When I try to drag and drop an app's icon to a new position it doesn't stay put.  When I move the mouse away from the launcher I'm unable to select anything at all, until I move the pointer back to the launcher and replace the icon in it's old location.

I've tried restarting unity, but the same problems persist. Any ideas?   Thanks!

Comment: this sounds like either a bug or that you need to reset unity back to its defaults.   Do you see this issue if you login to a new account?

Comment: Thanks for commenting.  I think it is a bug.  I've already reset unity to defaults and the problems persist.  I'll login to another account and update you with the details.  thx

Comment: Ok, the launcher works just fine under my guest account.  I'm able to arrange icons and lock/unlock them to the launcher bar.  I already attempted 'sudo apt-get install unity-scope-home' and 'unity --reset-icons'...  Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Try the unity-tweak-tool reset as per http://askubuntu.com/a/202020/14356

Comment: Ok, this partially resolved the issue.  I reset both gnome and unity as listed in the link.  At this point the indicators for locking/unlocking icons to the launcher don't work, but I've been able to arrange icons and lock programs to the launcher anyway.  For some reason I'm unable to unlock any programs (such as settings, amazon, libreoffice impress...)  Thanks for your help so far.  I'd love to be able to remove programs from my launcher, but at least now I don't need to locate the programs I use constantly in the dash.  Thanks!